# Changing layout menu in ASP.NET MVC 3 razor

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have web based od ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor in which I have defined layout used in every page + rendered body, nothing special. All I want to do is highlight selected name page in menu.

So here's my simple main menu using < ul >

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="1">@Html.ActionLink("menu1", "menu1", "Home")</li>
    <li id="2">@Html.ActionLink("menu2", "menu2", "Home")</li>
    <li id="2">@Html.ActionLink("menu3", "menu3", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

To my question: what is correct way to highlight selected < li > tag? I thought about using jQuery and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").click(function () {
        if (this.id == "1") {
            this.css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
        else if (this.id == "2") {
            this.css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
        else if (this.id == "3") {
            this.css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not working properly. Function is called everytime < li > is clicked but background of < li > is not changed. I'm not sure if it is caused by loading layout later (and overwriting background property of this list).

Next way I thought abous is somehow pass data through the controller, but I think it's not needed for such a small thing.

Every idea or thought is really appriciated!

Comment: Are you navigating away from the page when clicking the links?

Comment: This is code from layout page and everytime I click some < li > tag, I render body of document. So I'm not sure if it means I navigate away or not, probably not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside event handler `this` refers to pure DOM object. You need to wrap it into `$()` to call jQuery functions on it (like `css`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").click(function () {
        if (this.id == "1") {
            $(this).css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
        else if (this.id == "2") {
            $(this).css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
        else if (this.id == "3") {
            $(this).css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
    });
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hdqN/)

Comment: This will only work when you are not navigating away from the page when clicking a link.

Comment: @TimBJames, sure, I am just assuming OP has already sorted this out.

Comment: Thanks, this was my mistake. This works so the background gets changed for a while but then it's loaded back to the first background.

Comment: @OutOfSpaceHoneyBadger, most likely you have some other scripts working on the page (maybe event partial reload of the page). Of course each time the `ul` or any of its parts are reloaded you need to redefine its background, since essentially this is a new element. Look at the fiddle - once background is changed it does not disappear.

Comment: You are right. I disabled my other scripts and everything is fine - Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember it's not something as simple as doing .id once inside jQuery. Use an attribute selector for jQuery instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").click(function () {
        if (this.attr['id'] == "1") {
            this.css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
        else if (this.attr['id'] == "2") {
            this.css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
        else if (this.attr['id'] == "3") {
            this.css("background","#CCCCCC");
        }
    });
});
```

However, I think this is the wrong approach. Once you know that the current item has been clicked, the switch on id is irrelevant. I would do something a simple as give it a class when it's been active, making sure to remove the class from previous ones.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li").click(function () {
        // Remove class from others
        $("li.activeNav").removeClass("activeNav");

        // Add class to the one clicked
        $(this).addClass("activeNav");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
li.activeNav { background-color: #cccccc; }
```